# Logic Apps- Compare the modified date in the trigger body with the utcnow() and process only if it is within 1 day of utcnow()

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a use case where we are triggering the Logic App only when a record is modified in Salesforce. But the issue is that in testing we had disabled the Logic App for couple of days and when I enabled them back, some 35K records triggered our Logic Apps that overwhelmed the system.
So I am trying to add a trigger condition in my Logic App that would compare the last modified date from the trigger body with utcnow() and trigger the Logic App only if the last modified was within 1 day of UTC time. I tried a couple of conditions but nothing is working.

I tried the hardcoded value like below and it works.

```
@greater(triggerBody()?['LastModifiedDate'],'2022-02-02T17:25:49Z')
```

I am trying to modify this like but it is not working.

```
@greater(triggerBody()?['LastModifiedDate'],utcNow()-1)
@greater(equals(formatDateTime(triggerBody()?['LastModifiedDate'],'yyyy-MM-dd')),utcnow()-1)
```

I am new to Logic Apps and this kind of scenarios, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to adjust your logic for adding/minusing the days from a date, you need to use the `addDays` function.

This worked for me ...

```
@greater(formatDateTime(triggerBody()?['LastModifiedDate'], 'yyyy-MM-dd'), formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(), -1), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

... or this if you want to simply the formatting, they'll both do the same thing ...

```
@greater(triggerBody()?['LastModifiedDate'], addDays(utcNow(), -1))
```